# Why is my app cell phone not showing me my layouts as it shows in the emulator?

Tags: android, forms

I created this form and it works fine on emulator, but it does not showing me the content of this form on my phone. I checked it on different phones and on changing mobile the contents appears on different places.

Note: it works perfectly fine as it is specified in the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/r`enter code here`es/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.usman.registration.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="420dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/epi"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/kpk"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="New"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Registration"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Name Of Child:"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Gender"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Date Of Birth:"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Time Of Birth:"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Father/Mother Name:"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Father/Mother CNIC:"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Mobile # :"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Previous Dose (If Any) :"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorHint="#087d14" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="M"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textColor="#087d14" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="F"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textColor="#087d14" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:hint="Date"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorHint="#087d14" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:hint="Time"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorHint="#087d14" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorHint="#087d14" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="CNIC"
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorHint="#087d14" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Mobile no"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorHint="#087d14" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="OPV-0"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="OPV-1"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="OPV-2"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="OPV-3"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="IPV"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="PENTA-1"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="PENTA-2"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="PENTA-3"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="BCG"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox9"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="Hep-B"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox10"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="MEASLES-1"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox11"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="MEASLES-2"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox12"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="PCV10-1"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox13"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="PCV10-2"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox14"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="PCV10-3"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox15"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your emulator device and the original device have different resoultions

Comment: so how to solve this issue @NigamPatro ???

Comment: i want this app to run on every android phone

Comment: Because you set dp fix in layout this is it.,set diemnsion http://developer.android.com/intl/in/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html

Comment: Check with both the device, for supporting multiple screens refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: so what should i do to make this app work properly but the design remain the same as specified? @AjayPandya

Answer (score 0):

You have to define different different dimensions for different mobile screen resolutions.

like this

```
res/values/dimens.xml    
res/values-small/dimens.xml    
res/values-normal/dimens.xml    
res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

try below layout -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.usman.registration.MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="420dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="New"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Registration"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Name Of Child:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Date Of Birth:"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Time Of Birth:"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Father/Mother Name:"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Father/Mother CNIC:"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Mobile # :"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Previous Dose (If Any) :"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="#087d14" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="M"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="F"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textColor="#087d14" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="#087d14" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:hint="Time"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="#087d14" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="#087d14" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="CNIC"
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="#087d14" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Mobile no"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="#087d14" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="OPV-0"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="OPV-1"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="OPV-2"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="OPV-3"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    >

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="IPV"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="PENTA-1"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="PENTA-2"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="PENTA-3"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="BCG"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox9"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="Hep-B"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="MEASLES-1"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox11"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="MEASLES-2"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox12"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="PCV10-1"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox13"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="PCV10-2"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="PCV10-3"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox15"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#087d14" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

- Note- Please don't specify `height/width` in `dp`. You need to learn how to use `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`.